# Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool Parse Error

Tags: azure-synapse

When execute the script below on Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool I get the error:

```
Parse error at line: 11, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'FOR'.
```

However, I if execute the same code on Azure Synapse Serverless Pool it works fine.

```
DECLARE
    @EnrichedViewDatabase sysname, 
    @EnrichedViewSchema sysname, 
    @EnrichedColumnSuffix varchar(50),  
    @LanguageCode varchar(10), 
    @BaseTableSuffix varchar(50),
    @PreviewOnly bit, --Indicate whether to preview the SQL Script (without creating the views) = 1 ; Create views = 0;
    @CurrentDatabase sysname,
    @CurrentDatabaseSchema sysname

SET @EnrichedViewDatabase = 'DedicatedSQLPool'
SET @EnrichedViewSchema = 'dbo'
SET @EnrichedColumnSuffix = 'code'
SET @LanguageCode = 1033
SET @BaseTableSuffix = ''
SET @PreviewOnly = 0 
SET @CurrentDatabase = 'dataverse_montaguqa1_unq5a4857c03d0545c6b9ad616ca59a7'
SET @CurrentDatabaseSchema = 'dbo'

DECLARE @ColumnMetadata nvarchar(MAX), @ColumnMetadataSQL nvarchar(MAX)

--Define the SQL statement to retrieve column metadata from the Lake Database managed by Synapse Link for Dataverse
--Results will be stored as a JSON document in a variable
SET @ColumnMetadataSQL = 'SET @ColumnMetadataOUT = (
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, 
    TABLE_NAME, 
    COLUMN_NAME, 
    ORDINAL_POSITION, 
    DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''dbo''
    AND TABLE_NAME NOT IN (''OptionsetMetadata'', ''GlobalOptionsetMetadata'',''StateMetadata'',''StatusMetadata'', ''TargetMetadata'')
    AND TABLE_NAME LIKE ''%' + @BaseTableSuffix + '''
FOR JSON AUTO)'
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX);  
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@ColumnMetadataOUT NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT';  
EXECUTE sp_executesql @ColumnMetadataSQL, @ParmDefinition, @ColumnMetadataOUT=@ColumnMetadata OUTPUT;  

--Declare a variable to store a SQL statement for creating enriched views
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = ''
```

Any thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Clause** is available in SQL server, Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL MI.

- It is ***not*** supported in Azure Synapse Analytics.

[image]

**Image Reference:**
[FOR Clause (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-for-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

In synapse dedicated SQL pool, you can use **concat** and **string_agg** functions and create Json data manually instead of using **For JSON auto**. I tried this with sample data.

**Sample source data:**

[image]

Query to convert the table data in Json format:

```sql
select concat('{',string_agg(concat('{id:"',id,'",name:"',name,'"}'),','),'}')
as JSON_data from tab1
```

**Result:**
[image]

You can log a feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/9b9ba8e4-0825-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8).

Comment: Hi @Aswin, thanks for reaching. If it's not supported in Azure Synapse Analytics then can you explain why I'm able to use the code on Azure Synapse Serverless Pool?

Comment: Can you advise on the equivalent clause for Azure Synapse Analytics Dedicated Pool?

Comment: explain why I'm able to use the code on Azure Synapse Serverless Pool? --**I tried in Synapse serverless SQL pool. It worked and It is not working in dedicated SQL pool. You can check this with Product team. I have shared the link to raise a ticket with Product team.**

Comment: **Can you advise on the equivalent clause for Azure Synapse Analytics Dedicated Pool?** -- Edited the answer with query to convert the table data into json data